# ortools / linear programming - minimise cost of shopping basket across vendors

Tags: python, linear-programming, or-tools, constraint-programming

Being new to constraint programming and ORTools generally, i'm not sure how to take the next step in solving this problem..

Its the classic "minimise the cost of a shopping cart between multiple vendors" (sorry!!)

I've got python/ORTools calculating the minimum cost of the full basket (where possible), using a matrix of variables - item against number ordered from each vendor - but I want to add in the following to the model:

1. Shipping costs (which may change per vendor, and number of items from that vendor (eg :
   Vendor 1 : <=5 items = $1 shipping, >5 items = $2 shipping
   Vendor 2 : <=5 items = $1 shipping, >5 items = free shipping
2. Store credit - if I have store credit, i'd like to factor that in - prioritise using store credit first

If a complete basket cant be found (eg I want 10 items, but only 5 are in stock across all the vendors, is it possible to get the closest solution? (nearest being lowest price for the most amount of wanted items?) - currently it just says there is no solution found. (change line 18 - items[0] = 10 to trigger that)

Happy to go digging, but not really sure what to look for! Thanks!!

Code is below :

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

#prices at vendors of each item
#(eg item 2 is 0.05 at vendor 2)
allStockPrice = {}
allStockPrice[0] = [10, 11]
allStockPrice[1] = [0.15, 0.20]
allStockPrice[2] = [0.04, 0.05]

#stock at vendors of each item
allStockQty = {}
allStockQty[0] = [1, 6]
allStockQty[1] = [0, 2]
allStockQty[2] = [5, 1]

#number of each item that I want to purchase
items = {}
items[0] = 5
items[1] = 2
items[2] = 1

#create a variable array for the solver
#how many of each item am I ordering from each vendor?
variable_list = [[]] * len(items)
variable_list[0] = [[]] * len(allStockPrice[0])
variable_list[1] = [[]] * len(allStockPrice[0])
variable_list[2] = [[]] * len(allStockPrice[0])

def configure_objective(solver):
    global allStockPrice, variable_list

    objective = solver.Objective()

    #coefficient for each variable is the cost to purchase
    for i in items:
        for j in range(len(allStockPrice[0])):
            objective.SetCoefficient(variable_list[i][j], allStockPrice[i][j])

    objective.SetMinimization()

    return objective

def configure_constraints(solver):
    global allStockPrice, allStockQty, items, variable_list

    #can only have upto the maximum amount wanted of each item
    for i in items:
        solver.Add(sum(variable_list[i]) == items[i])

    #items must be in stock at the vendor
    for i in items:
        for j in range(len(allStockPrice[0])):
            solver.Add(variable_list[i][j] <= allStockQty[i][j])

def configure_variables(solver):
    global allStockPrice, allStockQty, items

    #must get between 0 and x items
    for i in items:
        for j in range(len(allStockPrice[0])):
            variable_list[i][j] = solver.IntVar(0, items[i], str('x_i%i_v%i' % (i, j)))

    return variable_list

def solve(solver):
    result_status = solver.Solve()
    return result_status


def print_solution(solver, result_status, variable_list, constraint_list):
    if result_status == solver.OPTIMAL:
        print('Successful solve.')
        # The problem has an optimal solution.
        print(('Problem solved in %f milliseconds' % solver.wall_time()))
        # The objective value of the solution.
        print(('Optimal objective value = %f' % solver.Objective().Value()))
        # The value of each variable in the solution.
        var_sum = 0

        print (variable_list)
        for variable in variable_list:
            for vendor in variable:
                print(('%s = %f' % (vendor.name(), vendor.solution_value())))
                var_sum += vendor.solution_value()
        print(('Variable sum = %f' % var_sum));

        print('Advanced usage:')
        print(('Problem solved in %d iterations' % solver.iterations()))

        for variable in variable_list:
            for vendor in variable:
                print(('%s: reduced cost = %f' % (vendor.name(), vendor.reduced_cost())))

    elif result_status == solver.INFEASIBLE:
        print('No solution found.')
    elif result_status == solver.POSSIBLE_OVERFLOW:
        print('Some inputs are too large and may cause an integer overflow.')

solver = pywraplp.Solver('SolveSimpleSystem', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)

variable_list = configure_variables(solver)
constraint_list = configure_constraints(solver)
objective = configure_objective(solver)

result_status = solve(solver)

print_solution(solver, result_status, variable_list, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try manually creating a solution, you'll see there isn't one.

`sum(variable_list[i]) == items[i]` with i = 0 is impossible to satisfy, you have a total of 7 units in stock, but you are forcing the solver to purchase 10.

If you want to find the "closest" solution you need to define an optimization problem where the closest to feasible solution is optimal, by using "soft constraints". The simplest way to do this in your example is by defining a fake 3rd supplier with infinite stock and very expensive items. This will only be used if the demand can't be satisfied by one of the regular suppliers.

See https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nBrMsUxCVea5PG8juzfdYPm4PdM6N9dJ?usp=sharing

Comment: Exactly, I understand that- the question is more like can this method be used to give a 'closest to the solution, if so, how?

Comment: Sure, you define an extra vendor with enough stock to satisfy the full demand which will sell you items at a cost of a million dollars each (ideally the smallest number that is clearly still impossible).

Comment: Interesting...OK, so in doing that my total basket would be the 10 items at a ridiculous cost. That doesn't get me closer to the partial solution...so we add a constraint that the total needs to be a total of less than 1x the large number as well.. let me try that out, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, no that additional constraint wouldn't work the way I thought...any other thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need an additional constraint. Just add the 3rd supplier, it should do exactly what you want - it should only order from the 3rd supplier if it's impossible to satisfy that demand elsewhere, and should happily order a fraction of the demand from 1 and/or 2 because they are cheaper.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nBrMsUxCVea5PG8juzfdYPm4PdM6N9dJ?usp=sharing

Comment: got it - i'd have to post process the result to strip the dummy vendor back out when presenting the solution - is that what you're suggesting? That works - looks like that requirement is met, thanks for the guidance! Any ideas on how to implement the other two parts? (additional shipping costs if a vendor is used, and store credit affects the final price paid at a vendor - I suppose they're both the same thing, but one making the total +ve and the other -ve)